# Diferencia de horas exactas entre sumaHoras y hrsDia, Excel PHP

Tags: php, php5, phpexcel

Quiero sacar la Diferencia exacta entre la Hora A y Hora B.

```
Ejemplo A
  HoraEntrada   HoraSalida      sumaHoras         hrsDia       Diferencia

    06:51:27       19:51:00        12:59         08:00:00       4.98
```

La siguiente consulta me retorna sumaHoras

```
$qry = "select 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada,
                convert(varchar(10), ((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)/3600)) + ':'+                  
                convert(varchar(10), (((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)%3600)/60))  as sumaHoras

            from tblasistencia where idclave = '".$empno."' and 
                fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 00:00:00',103) and 
                CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 23:59:59',103)";
```

Y hrsDia es una variable con diferentes horas, puede ser 07:00:00 o 09:30:00

Despues mando sumaHoras a una columna de excel junto con hrsDia, 
aqui saco la diferencia dividida entre 3600, el valor absoluto, y redondeo a 2 decimales.
Por lo cual obtengo la "Diferencia" especificado en el Ejemplo A es decir 4.98

```
->setCellValue('L'. $i,(($varSumaHoras=='')?'':round($suma=abs($suma=strtotime($datos['sumaHoras'])-strtotime($row['hrsDia']))/3600,2)))
```

Sin embargo el resultado correcto debe ser 4.58 y no 4.98
ya que si se mùltiplica 0.58 por 60 se obtienen los minutos.

Entonces quiero encontrar la forma de poder hacer esa operación(mùltiplicar 0.58 por 60 para que retorne 4.58) dentro de 
->setCellValue()

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué le das tanta vuelta a tus datos?, por ejemplo aquí: `convert(varchar(10), ((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)/3600))` eso no es bueno desde el punto de vista del rendimiento, ahí pareces hacer un cálculo con el dato en la consulta misma, o sea, a nivel de base de datos, para luego hacerlo también por programación a nivel de PHP. Yo creo que te estás ahogando en un vaso de agua. Es más, con el `SELECT` yo traería solamente mis dos columnas: `fechaEntrada` y `fechaSalida` y luego por programación calcularía lo que necesite con los datos y le daría formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para restar las fechas/horas prueba lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$fechaA = '2018-01-01 01:11:01';
$fechaB = '2018-01-01 02:22:00';

$diff = gmdate("H:i:s", strtotime($fechaB)-strtotime($fechaA));
```

Después, simplemente utiliza esa variable para almacenar el resultado en la celda excel.

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/TYm3Bl)**

**NOTA:**

Si sólo dispones de tiempo (sin fechas) puedes lograr lo mismo añadiendo delante una fecha:

```
<?php

$timeA = '01:11:01';
$timeB = '02:22:00';

$fechaA = "1970-01-01 $timeA";
$fechaB = "1970-01-01 $timeB";


# Formato HH:MM:SS
$diff = gmdate("H:i:s", strtotime($fechaB)-strtotime($fechaA));
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/ZHWlNT)**

La función [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) lo que hace es calcular el número de segundos que han pasado desde el 1 de enero de 1970. Después, restas el número de segundos de las dos fechas/tiempos y le das el formato que te interese con [gmdate](http://www.php.net/gmdate)

Answer (score 3):

No entiendo muy bien cómo de `$qry` obtienes  *Horas A*, porque no veo ningún alias en la query que aparezca en el ejemplo, pero creo que el problema no está ahí. De hecho, creo que no hay ningún problema, me explico:

Según lo que dices hacía el final:

> Despues mando HorasA como sumaHoras a una columna de excel y Horas B
>   como hrsDia, aqui saco la diferencia dividida entre 3600, el valor
>   absoluto, y redondeo a 2 decimales. Por lo cual obtengo la
>   "Diferencia" especificado en el Ejemplo A es decir 4.98
>
> (...)
>
> Sin embargo el resultado correcto debe ser 4.58 y no 4.98 ya que si se
>   mùltiplica 0.58 por 60 se obtienen los minutos.

He hecho el mismo cálculo (*Horas A* - *Horas B*) y me sale que la diferencia son 4 horas y 59 minutos. Tú indicas que a tí la diferencia te sale de 4.98, pero que debería ser 4.58.

El problema es que lo estás interpretando mal, porque el resultado está bien. Si multiplicas el 0.98 del 4.98 por 60 (conversión de fracción de hora por minutos en una hora), i.e.: 0.98 * 60, obtienes 58.8 minutos (~59 minutos), que seguro que si coges los decimales ocultos de 0.98, obtendrás los 59 minutos.

Para hacer el resultado más comprensible, se me ocurren varais maneras:

- Que el título de la celda sea "Diferencia (horas). De esta manera indicas la unidad y si alguien quiere sacar los minutos, lo podrá hacer multiplicando la parte decimal por 60.
- Transformar el contenido de numérico a fecha, en vez de tener el formato 4.98, que sea 4:59.
  Algo así como (no lo he probado):

  ```
   $diferencia = round($suma=abs($suma=strtotime($datos['sumaHoras'])-strtotime($row['hrsDia']))/3600,2))
   ->setCellValue('L'. $i,(($varSumaHoras=='')?'':sprintf('%02d:%02d', (int) $diferencia, fmod($diferencia, 1) * 60))
  ```
- Dividir el resultado en dos celdas: La diferencia se compone de las celdas "Horas" y "Minutos".
  Algo así como (no lo he probado):

  ```
   // calcular la diferencia
   $diferencia = round($suma=abs($suma=strtotime($datos['sumaHoras'])-strtotime($row['hrsDia']))/3600,2)
   // separar la diferencia por el punto para obtener la unidad y el decimal en valores separados
   list($whole, $decimal) = explode('.', $diferencia);
   // escribir la parte completa en una celda
   ->setCellValue('L'. $i,(($varSumaHoras=='')?'':whole))
   // escribir la parte decimal en otra celda, pero multiplicandola por 60
   ->setCellValue('M'. $i,(($varSumaHoras=='')?'':decimal*60))
  ```

Espero haberme explicado bien. Cualquier cosa, me comentas.

Un saludo,

Unai

Comment: Exacto, pero deseo hacer màs fácil la interpretaciòn de ese resultado por parte del usuario. Quiero encontrar la forma de hacer ese calculo, dentro de ->setCellValue()

Comment: @NetzaL, he incluido varias opciones. Mira a ver si es lo que buscas.

Comment: Ya edite mejor el cuestionamiento, pero basicamente es eso "Dividir el resultado en dos celdas: La diferencia se compone de las celdas "Horas" y "Minutos". excepto por lo de dividir las celdas en Horas y Minutos, voy a intentar implementarlo, y comento el resultado

Comment: @NetzaL si mi respuesta te ha servido, por favor, márcala como respuesta. :)

Answer (score 2):

Al ver la siguiente consulta:

```
$qry = "select 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada,
                convert(varchar(10), ((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)/3600)) + ':'+                  
                convert(varchar(10), (((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)%3600)/60))  as sumaHoras

            from tblasistencia where idclave = '".$empno."' and 
                fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 00:00:00',103) and 
                CONVERT(DATETIME, '".$fechainicio." 23:59:59',103)";
```

Uno tiene la impresión de que de entrada te estás ahogando en un vaso de agua.

Dejaré el siguiente criterio a tu consideración:

Escribir una consulta SQL cuyos resultados estén destinados a un lenguaje de programación (PHP u otro), en **donde repitas una y otra vez** columnas como `fechaSalida`, `fechaEntrada` aplicando tareas como conversiones, cálculos, formateo, etc, etc, lo que hace es recargar innecesariamente al manejador de base de datos.

Mi propuesta es muy simple:

- Obtén de la base de datos los datos que necesites, sin tantas repeticiones, cálculos, conversiones
- Da tratamiento a los datos obtenidos por programación

Si aplicamos esto, tu consulta SQL quedaría así:

```
$qry = "SELECT 
                fechaSalida,
                fechaEntrada,
        FROM tblasistencia 
        WHERE  ....
       ";
```

Lo que se hace aquí es simplemente traer los datos tal cual a PHP y a partir de ahí puedes hacer los cálculos que quieras.

PHP cuenta con la poderosa clase `DateTime` la cual te permite **crear un verdadero objeto fecha** a partir de una fecha/hora bien representadas. Con esa clase nada más tienes que crear dos objetos fecha y a partir de ellos hacer cualquier tipo de operación, cálculo, formato, etc.

Supongamos que `fechaEntrada` y `fechaSalida` arrojan estos valores:

```
$fechaEntrada="2018-10-03 06:51:27";
$fechaSalida ="2018-10-03 19:51:00";
```

Creamos dos objetos a partir de ellos:

```
$fechaIn=new DateTime($fechaEntrada);
$fechaOut=new DateTime($fechaSalida);
```

Pues bien, tanto `$fechaIn` como `$fechaOut` son dos objetos con todas las de la ley que representan tus datos de salida/llegada.

Si quieres veamos uno de ellos por dentro:

```
var_dump($fechaIn);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-10-03 06:51:27.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

### ¿Y qué hago con dos objetos, de qué me sirve?

Que **a partir de ellos puedes hacer cuántos cálculos y representaciones quieras**, expresados en horas, minutos, segundos, letras, días, semanas, trimestres...

Veamos algunos ejemplos de representación (nótese que siempre usamos el mismo objeto, no es que creamos una y otra vez el objeto como se hace en tu consulta SQL):

```
echo $fechaIn->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
echo $fechaIn->format('Y-m-d').PHP_EOL;
echo $fechaIn->format('H:i:s').PHP_EOL;
echo $fechaIn->format('g:i A').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
2018-10-03 06:51:27
2018-10-03
06:51:27
6:51 AM
```

No es sólo formato, también podemos **hacer cálculos**. Por ejemplo, no logré descifrar el cálculo que quieres hacer aquí:

```
convert(varchar(10), ((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)/3600)) + ':'+                  
                convert(varchar(10), (((DATEDIFF(SECOND, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida)%86400)%3600)/60))  as sumaHoras
```

pero **sea cual sea el cálculo** lo puedes hacer a partir de tus dos objetos y al mismo tiempo expresarlo en un formato dado.

Supongamos que quieres saber cuántas horas han pasado entre la entrada y la salida:

```
$timeWorking = $fechaIn->diff($fechaOut);
```

Lo que produce `$timeWorking` no es una variable cualquiera, es también un objeto con una cantidad de información que alucinas. Veámoslo por dentro:

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (15) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(0)
  ["h"]=>
  int(12)
  ["i"]=>
  int(59)
  ["s"]=>
  int(33)
  ["weekday"]=>
  int(0)
  ["weekday_behavior"]=>
  int(0)
  ["first_last_day_of"]=>
  int(0)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_type"]=>
  int(0)
  ["special_amount"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_weekday_relative"]=>
  int(0)
  ["have_special_relative"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Entre la información que tiene `$timeWorking` tenemos la cantidad de años `y`, meses `m`, días `d`, horas `h`  .... que han transcurrido entre los dos objetos originales  y muchas más cosas.

Y la cosa no termina ahí, si quieres presentar esa información de una forma determinada, puedes usar **otro método aplicado a ese mismo objeto**. Por ejemplo:

```
echo $timeWorking->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

**Salida:**

```
12:59:33
```

---

### Conclusión

> Lamento si me he alargado un poco en la explicación.
>
> La respuesta iba orientada a mostrar la potencia de los **objetos**.
>   En casos como estos conviene cargar los menos posible al manejador de
>   base de datos, traer nuestra información de la forma más sencilla
>   posible y luego echar mano de las posibilidades del lenguaje (en este
>   caso la clase `DateTime` de PHP) para manipular esa información.
>
> Espero que la respuesta sea de utilidad. Lo que propongo es enfocar la
>   solución del problema desde otro punto, simplificando el código.

---

**NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**

La consulta SQL que estás lanzando desde PHP es **altamente vulnerable a ataques de Inyección SQL.** Considera el uso de consultas preparadas para neutralizar esa posibilidad de ataque que podría traer consecuencias lamentables sobre tus datos o sobre tu sistema mismo.

Comment: Ya edite mejor el cuestionamiento, el alias  sumaHoras es Horas A hasta antes de editar la prgunta, ahora es solo sumaHoras.

Comment: SumaHoras me retorna la diferencia en horas y minutos,posteriormente ese resultado se lo resto a HorasDia que es una variable (puede ser: 8:00:00, 9:00:00: 21:00:00 etc) sin embargo esa resta la hago en ->setCellValue() con $suma=strtotime($datos['sumaHoras'])-strtotime($row['hrsDia']))/3600,2))

Comment: con la ayuda de strtotime() sin embargo los resultados me lo arroja como (Ejemplo A) Diferencia 4.98, y es aquí en donde quiero implementar alguna otra operación para poder sacar el resultado exacto

Comment: @NetzaL todavía no entiendo con claridad lo que quieres, ni tampoco entiendo cómo están tus datos. Yo creo que aquí el problema es que estás partiendo de una consulta SQL mal planteada y ahora quieres forzosamente adaptar el resto del código a los resultados que te arroja dicha consulta. Lo que intento con mi respuesta es mostrar otra vía de solución mucho más clara, más rápida y más acorde a las capacidades del lenguaje donde se manejarán los datos. Si editas la pregunta exponiendo claramente el contexto (sin asumir que la consulta SQL debe ser como la tienes sí o sí) creo que ayudará mucho.